# How to name subelements according to BEM?

Tags: html, css, class, bem

I have a question regarding BEM (Block Element Modifier) class naming conventions.

What if I need to have 3 nested divs, how should I name the class of the 3rd one?

```css
.one{} //block
.one__two{} //block element
//?
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="one__two">
  
    <!-- How should I rename class "three"? -->
    <div class="three"></div> 
    
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to rename ".three" to "one__two__three", or "two__three", but I'm not sure that this is right, because as I understand, according to BEM nesting elements inside of elements is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it's about relationships, particularly key-value relationships, so I would approach it that way.

Without exploring contextual naming paradigms, it could be suggested to use `one__three`.

Alternatively, if `one` is simply a container for `two`, then `one` could be renamed `two__container` and `three` renamed to `two__item`. Of course that doesn't make a whole lot of sense using numbered labels like this, but I hope you can see where it could lead.

Comment: Thank you, of course, numbered labels were added for the sake of simplicity here. Interesting, so the key-value approach puts the most important element first, and after it, we can add something secondary even in it is a parent of a key element, do I understand correctly? So basically the naming order does not represent the nesting order in this case.

Comment: `one__three` is OK: then it is an element of `one`. But `two__container` / `two__item` is not BEM compliant. You can do `two` / `two__item` (a child block `two` and its element) or `one__three-container` / `three` (an element of `one` and a child block `three`).

Answer (score 0):

Nesting elements is fine; build the structure to your needs. The important thing is to not couple the classnames to your nesting. The classname schema does really only recognize two types of DOM elements: the block itself and the elements of that block; of the latter all are equal regarding the naming schema, no matter how deeply nested in the block.
Here is an example:

```html
<div class="product-card">
  <div class="product-card__img-area">
    <img class="product-card__product-picture" src="https://example.com/cabulator.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card__header">
    <span class="product-card__main-headline">Encabulator</span>
    <span class="product-card__sub-headline">The turbo shmeerf of all Shmoof</span>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card__text-body">
    Lorem ipsum shmeerf of Shmoof quooz bar moof bla bla
  </div>
  <div class="product-card__footer">
    <a class="product-card__cta" href="https://example.com/buy.html">Buy it!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And modifiers are added as needed:

```html
  <div class="product-card__footer">
    <a class="product-card__cta product-card__cta--bargain" href="http://exmpl.com/buy">
      Buy it! 50% off for first-time customers!!!!!! OMG!!!!
    </a>
  </div>
```